# How to SELECT every row that has a duplicate value of a field

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Using PostgreSQL, I'm trying to find a way to select *every* row that duplicate values for a certain column.

For example, my table would look like this:

```
id   | username | email
1    | abc      | abc@test.com
2    | abc1     | abc@test.com
3    | def      | def@test.com
4    | ghi      | ghi@test.com
5    | ghi1     | ghi@test.com
```

And my desired output would select the username and the email, where email count > 2:

```
abc   | abc@test.com
abc1  | abc@test.com
ghi   | ghi@test.com
ghi1  | ghi@test.com
```

I have tried `group by having`, and that gets me close to what I want, but I don't think I want to use `group by` because that will actually combine the rows with duplicate values, I still want to show the separate rows that contain duplicate values.

```
SELECT email FROM auth_user
GROUP BY email HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

That only shows me the emails that have duplicate values:

```
abc@test.com
ghi@test.com
```

I can include the count in there with `SELECT email, count(*) FROM ...` but that's not what I want either.

I'm thinking I want something like `where count(email) > 1` but that gives me an error saying `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

How can I select duplicate values without grouping them?

**Update with Solution**:

@GordonLinoff posted the correct answer. But to match my exact needs of only obtaining username and email fields, I have modified his a little bit (which should be self explanatory, but posting in case anyone else needs the exact query)

```
select username, email
from (select username, email, count(*) 
      over (partition by email) as cnt
      from auth_user au
) au
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the original rows, then I would suggest using `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select au.*
from (select au.*, count(*) over (partition by email) as cnt
      from auth_user au
     ) au
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I love how you answered that within 5 seconds of my posting the question. Guess I need to study more on my SQL. I will accept your answer in 11 more minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful too:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from auth_user t1, auth_user t2
where t1.id != t2.id
and t1.email = t2.email
```